# Reference variables from another eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Is there any way in java to call a int or a string from another project(app) and change it.

Example:

If I create a new project called Project1, and a class in it.

in the class I will putt a int (`int a = 0;`)

And if I create the 2nd project (app) width another class called "classPtwo" in it.

In that class, how do I call the int from the 1st project(app) and change it, or `println` it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to add the other project to the class/buildpath.... Other than that, I have no idea what you are trying to do or why

Comment: try by adding project1 to buildpath of project2

Comment: Can you show me an example in the code? How do I do that width the path

Comment: Are you familiar with `import`, `private`, `public` and the concept of getters and setters?

Comment: @Salmeh Create a jar of Project1 and add it to the classpath of Project2. In your Project 2 create a new Object of Project1's class and set your int and print the same.

Answer (score 0):

`Project` is `project`. Variables you set the value with will all be garbaged after the program terminated.

Yes you can reference those variables if they are in separate package, having getters or static keyword with proper access modifiers in the same project, But you have to expose those data or include as JAR from one project and read it from another if you really need to access that data from another project.